# How to use trackpad scrolling in .Net

Tags: .net, scroll, input-devices, trackpad

My WinForms app uses the mouse wheel, subscribing to the `Control.MouseWheel` event. How can I get it to work with scrolling methods from other input devices, in particular "finger along the edge" scrolling on the (Synaptics) trackpad on my T61? I assume that I need to wire up the trackpad messages to the `Control.MouseWheel` event somehow, but I have no idea where to start...

EDIT: This is currently not working; so my trackpad is evidently not sending `Control.MouseWheel` messages.

Thanks!

(I am using C#, but this is surely .Net general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lenovo drivers don't work the way that you'd hope. There's a workaround, posted here: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markrideout/datagridview-mouse-scrolling-button-with-ibmultranav-driver) which involves tricking the mouse driver into recognizing that you want scroll messages.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged for good reasons, e.g. the target of the link can cease to exist, like here.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20100610085442/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/12/datagridview-mouse-scrolling-button-with-ibm-ultranav-driver.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If it is just your machine, then easiest thing to do is to edit TP4table.dat file and add application name in it, as explained here: http://www.syaoran.net/blog/2010/01/how-to-enable-thinkpad-trackpoint-scrolling/

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @oddRaven it is not my blog, so I can't do a thing. You still have some clue from my answer on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the scrolling action on a trackpad simply sends the same signals to the PC as the scroll wheel on a mouse so your current implementation should work.

Comment: They should send mouse wheel messages, but Synaptics drivers do not. They actually look for native Windows scroll bars and manipulate them. And Synaptics touch pads seem to be the most widely used.